# Disconnected Input in Gradient of Theano Scan Op

Tags: python, theano

I have a number of items in groups of varying size. For each of these groups, one (known) item is the "correct" one.  There is a function which will assign a score to each of item. This results in a flat vector of item scores, as well as vectors telling the index where each group begins and how big it is.  I wish to do a "softmax" operation over the scores in each group to assign the items probabilities, and then take the sum of the logs of the probabilities of the correct answers. Here is a simpler version, where we simply return the score of the correct answer without the softmax and the logarithm.

```
import numpy                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                          
import theano                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                         
import theano.tensor as T                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                             
from theano.printing import Print                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                     

def scoreForCorrectAnswer(groupSize, offset, correctAnswer, preds):  
    # for each group, this will get called with the size of
    # the group, the offset of where the group begins in the 
    # predictions vector, and which item in that group is correct                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                              
    relevantPredictions = preds[offset:offset+groupSize]                                                                                                                                                                                                                              
    ans = Print("CorrectAnswer")(correctAnswer)                                                                                                                                                                                                                                       
    return relevantPredictions[ans]       

groupSizes = T.ivector('groupSizes')                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                  
offsets = T.ivector('offsets')                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                        
x = T.fvector('x')                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                    
W = T.vector('W')                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                     
correctAnswers = T.ivector('correctAnswers')                                                                                                                                                                                                                                          

# for this simple example, we'll just score the items by
# element-wise product with a weight vector                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                  
predictions = x * W                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                   

(values, updates) = theano.map(fn=scoreForCorrectAnswer,                                                                                                                                                                                                                                       
   sequences = [groupSizes, offsets, correctAnswers],                                                                                                                                                                                                                                
   non_sequences = [predictions] )                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                    

func = theano.function([groupSizes, offsets, correctAnswers,                                                                                                                                                                                                                          
        W, x], [values])                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                              

sampleInput = numpy.array([0.1,0.7,0.3,0.05,0.3,0.3,0.3], dtype='float32')                                                                                                                                                                                                            
sampleW = numpy.array([1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0], dtype='float32')                                                                                                                                                                                                           
sampleOffsets = numpy.array([0,4], dtype='int32')                                                                                                                                                                                                                                     
sampleGroupSizes = numpy.array([4,3], dtype='int32')                                                                                                                                                                                                                                  
sampleCorrectAnswers = numpy.array([1,2], dtype='int32')                                                                                                                                                                                                                              

data = func (sampleGroupSizes, sampleOffsets, sampleCorrectAnswers, sampleW, sampleInput)                                                                                                                                                                                             
print data                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                            

#these all three raise the same exception (see below)                                                                                                                                                                                                                                             
gW1 = T.grad(cost=T.sum(values), wrt=W)                                                                                                                                                                                                                                               
gW2 = T.grad(cost=T.sum(values), wrt=W, disconnected_inputs='warn')                                                                                                                                                                                                                   
gW3 = T.grad(cost=T.sum(values), wrt=W, consider_constant=[groupSizes,offsets])
```

This correctly calculates the output, but when I attempt to take the gradient with respect to the parameter `W`, I get (paths abbreviated):

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test_scan_for_stackoverflow.py", line 37, in <module>
    gW = T.grad(cost=T.sum(values), wrt=W)
  File "Theano-0.6.0rc2-py2.7.egg/theano/gradient.py", line 438, in grad
    outputs, wrt, consider_constant)
  File "Theano-0.6.0rc2-py2.7.egg/theano/gradient.py", line 698, in _populate_var_to_app_to_idx
    account_for(output)
  File "Theano-0.6.0rc2-py2.7.egg/theano/gradient.py", line 694, in account_for
    account_for(ipt)
  File "Theano-0.6.0rc2-py2.7.egg/theano/gradient.py", line 669, in account_for
    connection_pattern = _node_to_pattern(app)
  File "Theano-0.6.0rc2-py2.7.egg/theano/gradient.py", line 554, in _node_to_pattern
    connection_pattern = node.op.connection_pattern(node)
  File "Theano-0.6.0rc2-py2.7.egg/theano/scan_module/scan_op.py", line 1331, in connection_pattern
ils)
  File "Theano-0.6.0rc2-py2.7.egg/theano/scan_module/scan_op.py", line 1266, in compute_gradient
    known_grads={y: g_y}, wrt=x)
  File "Theano-0.6.0rc2-py2.7.egg/theano/gradient.py", line 511, in grad
    handle_disconnected(elem)
  File "Theano-0.6.0rc2-py2.7.egg/theano/gradient.py", line 497, in handle_disconnected
    raise DisconnectedInputError(message)
theano.gradient.DisconnectedInputError: grad method was asked to compute 
the gradient with respect to a variable that is not part of the 
computational graph of the cost, or is used only by a 
non-differentiable operator: groupSizes[t]
```

Now, the `groupSizes` are constant, so there's no reason to need to take any gradients with respect to it.  Ordinarily you could deal with this by either suppressing `DisconnectedInputError`s or telling Theano to treat `groupSizes` as a constant in your `T.grad` call (see the last lines of the sample script). But there doesn't seem to be any way to pass such things down to the internal `T.grad` calls in the gradient computation for the `ScanOp`.

Am I missing something? Is these a way to get the gradient computation to work through the ScanOp here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This turns out to be a Theano bug as of mid-Feb. 2013 (0.6.0rc-2). It is fixed in the development version on github as of the date of this post.